# Simplifying the trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

$$\sin(x)\cos(x)\tan(x) + \frac{2\sin(x)\cos^3(x)}{\sin(2x)}$$

Can someone please show me step by step working of how I may be able to solve this?

Comment: a) What's the definition of $\tan x$, b) double-angle formula for $\sin (2x)$.

Comment: That's an expression, not an equation. I assume you mean "simplify," in which case you'll want to recall the definition of tangent and some double-angle identities.

Comment: Sorry. I'm looking to simplify using the trigonometrical identities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

1.
$$2\sin(x)\cos(x)=\sin(2x)$$
2.
$$\sin(x)\cos(x)\tan(x)=\sin^2(x)$$
3.
$$\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$$

Comment: Hi. How does sin(x)cos(x)tan(x)= sin^2(x)?

Comment: @Sugi If$$\sin(x)\cos(x)\tan(x)=\sin(x)\cos(x)\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=\frac{\sin^2(x) \cos(x)}{\cos(x)}=\sin^2(x)$$